# How to check exactly what apt install [some package] is going to do?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to compile a C++ project and got an error: `xxx.so no such file or directory`. In this case, normally I execute the command `apt-cache search xxx` and I can usually find a package name like `xxx-dev`, so then I simply execute `apt install xxx-dev` and it will be OK.

But in fact I don't know exactly what `apt install xxx-dev` will do. When we execute `apt install xxx-dev`, we can get some information about what would be installed, etc, but I want to know something more.

If I execute `apt install xxx-dev`, will it install more things than I need? For example, the error at the beginning told me that `xxx.so` was missing, however, when I execute `apt install xxx-dev`, I can usually see that many packages will be installed. Are all of these necessary? Is there a way to check exactly what `apt install xxx-dev`  will do or to check what a deb package contains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simulate the results of installing a package without actually installing it. Open the terminal and type:

```
apt install --simulate package-name
```

#### Results

- `The following additional packages will be installed:`
- `Suggested packages:`
- `The following NEW packages will be installed:`
- `X upgraded, X newly installed, X to remove and X not upgraded.` The X's are replaced by numbers. Example: `0 upgraded, 99 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.`
- `Inst`  - indicates packages that will be installed (99 lines in the above example, one package on each line)
- `Conf`  - indicates packages that will be configured